# PHP Regex to Match Only Certain Characters

Tags: php, regex

I would to check if the user submitted a valid title. The title must *only* contain:

1. alphabetic characters (lower or uppercase)
2. numbers
3. spaces
4. parentheses
5. single and double quotes
6. check that the title is not filled only with single or double quotes
   to circumvent the above regexp.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: 1-5 would be a straightfoward character class. #6 would be too. But you might have to run more than one match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that would work:

```
/^(?!['"]+$)[a-z\d \(\)'"]+$/i
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iN5pH9/1)

To use it in PHP code, do something like this:

```
$str = 'foo234234bar()"""';
$regex = '/^(?![\'"]+$)[a-z\d \(\)\'"]+$/i';

if (preg_match($regex, $str)) {
    echo "match found!";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

[**PHP Demo**](http://ideone.com/2BNfcg)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
if(
    preg_match('/^[a-z0-9] ](])\'\"]+$/i',$string) && 
    strlen(preg_replace('/[\'\"]+/','',$string)))){
//passed
}
else{
//failed
}
```